# How to calculate the volume of an egg

Tags: volume

Hi would you know how to calculate the volume of a chicken egg with a height of 47cm width of 39 and weight of 42g.(not the water displacement method)
thanks for your time.

Comment: If you make the assumption that an egg takes the form of an ellipsoid (which it technically is not), then you get a fairly good approximation of its volume

Comment: 47 *centimeters* is an awfully big egg. I think you mean 47mm (and likewise for the unspecified 39).

Comment: Volume is $\int_0^{2\pi}(\int_0^{47} f(x)dx)d\theta$ where $y= f(x)$ is a formula for determining how wide, $y$, the egg is and height of $x$.  An ellipse has a formula of $\frac {x^2}{(\frac {47}2)^2} + \frac {y^2}{(\frac {39}2)^2} = 1$.  Weight has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: You haven't describe what kind of egg shape you want. [How about this?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moss%27s_Egg). Just in case the picture in wiki is later removed, [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRM00.png).

Comment: If you know the density of an egg (which I don't; please ask the chemistry guys for this), then you can simply use $$\text{Volume} = \frac{\text{Mass}}{\text{Density}}$$